# Need help in setting up an HTTPS proxy using node.js, which picks up all the HTTPS requests from the browser window

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to set up an HTTPS proxy server using node.js. It needs to pick up all the HTTPS requests from the browser window. I have a mac book and I have configured the proxy setting from the preferences for HTTPS. Below is the sample code for capturing any browser requests, is this code correct? I am generating the keys using the following commands.

```
 openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 1024
 openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out certrequest.csr
 openssl x509 -req -in certrequest.csr -signkey privatekey.pem -out certificate.pem

var options = {
https: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem', 'utf8')
},
target: {
    https: true
}
};

https.createServer(options,function(request, response) {
console.log(request);
handleRequest(request, response);
}).listen(8877);
```

So the above code does not work, any suggestions how i can solve this problem, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy which is an http proxy for node.js. With it, all you would have to do is

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var options = {
  https: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem', 'utf8')
  }
};
var port = SOME_PORT;
var host = 'SOME_HOST';
httpProxy.createServer(port, host, options).listen(8877);
```

Comment: Yaa thanks, I will look at that, but i need to pick up every request made from the browser, adding a static host, wont that defeat the purpose?

Comment: Most likely yes. How does the browser send the requests to your server?

Comment: I mean for setting up an HTTP proxy      http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    handleRequest(request, response);
}).listen(8877);         The request object receives the request from the browser

Comment: So what is your question? How to implement `handleRequest`?

Comment: I looked at your solution and it worked for static hosts perfectly, thanks for that, I think the next step would be if I can get the requesting url and then put that value in the host variable.

Comment: So I guess my question here would be, could I get the HTTPS request made by the user from the browser and pass it to the host variable?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know that you vary the `host`, I think you should rather build an http server that performs the proxying using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). Something like this (based on [the `request` documentation](https://github.com/mikeal/request#streaming)):

```
var https = require('https'),
    request = require('request');
var options = {
    https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem', 'utf8')
    },
    target: {
        https: true
    }
};

https.createServer(options,function(req, resp) {
    var otherhost = req.some_method_to_get_host;
    console.log(req);
    req.pipe(request(otherhost)).pipe(resp)
}).listen(8877);
```